# Rootfolder option not working in Modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set

I am working in SP 2010 to SharePoint online migration.

I have a document library with 1000 document sets in it.
In a custom page I need to add this document library webpart and pass document set name in the url as query string in order to make that library webpart to display only documents uploaded in that document set.

In SharePoint 2010, we were able to do this by passing Rootfolder value in querystring.
Eg:
**&Rootfolder=/sitename/libraryname/documentsetname**

But in SharePoint online, it is not working.
If we pass Rootfolder, getting No items Exist error message,
If I pass id(**&id=/sitename/libraryname/documentsetname**), getting **Cant load the application on this page**.

Any idea how I need to pass the document set name in querysting, so that view will automatically display only documents inside that particular document set.
Thanks